# Where can I find a full list of wpa-* options for the interfaces file?

Tags: linux, debian, dbus, wpa-supplicant, wpa

I'm looking for an exhaustive list of wpa-* options that can be used in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

The Debian wiki has a how-to-use page here: https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse, which refers to `/usr/share/doc/wpasupplicant/README.modes.gz` for "additional" wpa-* options, but this file doesn't contain an exhaustive list, only a list of common options.

Where can I find a list of every available wpa-* option?

Failing that, is there an option to specify that wpa_supplicant be started with D-Bus enabled?

**EDIT:** On enabling D-Bus, looking in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/functions.sh`, there doesn't appear to be any code that adds a `-u` to the `WPA_SUP_OPTIONS` variable. I added it manually to my own `functions.sh` in the initialisation of `WPA_SUP_OPTIONS`:

```
init_wpa_supplicant () {
        [ -n "$WPA_SUP_CONF" ] || return 0

        local WPA_SUP_OPTIONS
        WPA_SUP_OPTIONS="-s -B -P $WPA_SUP_PIDFILE -i $WPA_IFACE -u"
                                                   inserted here ^^
```

I'm not sure if this script is universal, or specific to Debian.

Comment: The [example config](http://hostap.epitest.fi/gitweb/gitweb.cgi?p=hostap-06.git;a=blob_plain;f=wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf;hb=HEAD) "lists all available option".

Comment: @jasonwryan: That's a different set of options. I'm after the ones you use in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/etc/wpa_supplicant/functions.sh` is what you're interested in. Look at the `conf_wpa_supplicant` function.  In there, look for all of the calls to the `wpa_cli_do` function; you're interested in the 4th or 5th argument (if set_argument is the 3rd arg, then you want the 5th) to each call.

Here's a list I extracted quickly from the file with some shell magic:

```
wpa-ap-scan
wpa-preauthenticate
wpa-psk
wpa-wep-key[0..3]
wpa-altsubject-match
wpa-altsubject-match2
wpa-anonymous-identity
wpa-auth-alg
wpa-bssid
wpa-ca-cert
wpa-ca-cert2
wpa-ca-path
wpa-ca-path2
wpa-client-cert
wpa-client-cert2
wpa-dh-file
wpa-dh-file2
wpa-eap
wpa-eap-methods
wpa-eapol-flags
wpa-eappsk
wpa-engine
wpa-engine-id
wpa-fragment-size
wpa-freq-list
wpa-frequency
wpa-group
wpa-identity
wpa-id-str
wpa-key-id
wpa-key-mgmt
wpa-mode
wpa-nai
wpa-pac-file
wpa-pairwise
wpa-password
wpa-pcsc
wpa-peerkey
wpa-phase1
wpa-phase2
wpa-pin
wpa-priority
wpa-private-key
wpa-private-key2
wpa-private-key-passwd
wpa-private-key-passwd2
wpa-proactive-key-caching
wpa-proto
wpa-scan-freq
wpa-scan-ssid
wpa-ssid
wpa-subject-match
wpa-subject-match2
wpa-wep-tx-keyidx
```